# Replace first sign in line (linux bash)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to delete first sign in a file (without creating new file). That is the line (and this line isn't the first one or last one):

```
#$config['rrdcached']   = "unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock";
```

I'm trying to do thuis with sed command but it doesn't work. That is my command:

```
sed -i "s/#$config\['rrdcached'\].*$/$config\['config'\]/g" text.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Escape `$` in `sed -i "s/#\$config\['rrdchaed'\]....`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` characters are causing two problems.

First, the shell is treating `$config` as a variable reference, and replacing it with the value. You need to escape the `$` to prevent that.

Second, `$` has special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape it at that level as well. So you need to escape the backslash and the `$`.

```
sed -i "s/^#\\\$config\['rrdcached'\].*\$/\$config['config']/" text.txt
```

There's no need for the `g` modifier since you only want to replace the first match on the line. And you should use the `^` anchor so it only matches this at the beginning of the line.

It's also not necessary to escape special regexp characters in the replacement string.

Comment: Sorry, I started changing it to use single quotes, realized that wouldn't work, and didn't change it back completely.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the first match of # with following command:

```
sed -i '1 s/#//' test.txt
```

Comment: I think he only wants to do this on the `$config` line, not remove all `#` in the file. And he also needs to change `rrdcached` to `config` on that line.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "config" (thanks for that), but my command replaces only the first `#` in line number one. (There is no `g` at the end.)

Comment: The question says "this line isn't the first or last one".

Comment: You're right. I was irritated by "first sign in a file".

Answer (score 0):

This command works, but i forgot that there is something after '='. At now, everything after that is deleted.

I wrote this:

```
sed -i "s/^#\\\$config\['rrdcached'\] = "unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock";.*\$/\\\$config\['config'\]/ = "unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock";" text.txt
```